# How to assign ruby's OpenStruct attribute using a variable

Tags: ruby

How do I assign ruby's OpenStruct attribute using a variable instead of a pre-defined name.  I can do the following,

```
os = OpenStruct.new
os.one = 1
os.two = "Two"
```

But how do I make it so the attribute name is a variable?
For example:

```
attr_name = "sand_box"
os.#{attr_name} = "Play time!"   #### this doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'ostruct'
os = OpenStruct.new
os.one = 1
os.two = "Two"


attr_name = "sand_box"
os[attr_name] = "Play time!"

p os #-> #<OpenStruct one=1, two="Two", sand_box="Play time!">
```

Comment: @cfpete: [They do](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D). Although I guess it could be made clearer by using a variable for `:age`.

Comment: @cremno, you are correct... I missed that.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could just call the setter method:

```
os.public_send(:"#{attr_name}=", 'Play time!')
```